# The clock hand is not rotating action script 3

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

```
import flash.events.Event;

var time:Date = new Date();
var sec:int = time.seconds;

hour_mc.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,Rot);

function Rot(e:Event):void
{
        hour_mc.rotation = sec*6;

}
```

I want to make a clock with event listener in action script 3, but when I run this movie it just shows the current second and doesn't move.  What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first line creates a Date Object out of whatever timestamp is retrieved when the application starts, and you store the seconds value as an integer correctly, but that timestamp and that seconds value never change, so all you are doing is constantly multiplying the same value by 6 repeatedly. The simplest fix would be to move those two lines into the Rot function:

```
import flash.events.Event;

hour_mc.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,Rot);
function Rot(e:Event):void
{
    var time:Date = new Date();
    var sec:int = time.seconds;
    hour_mc.rotation = sec*6;
}
```